# Javascript replace all string contains '[]' doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, replaceall

I am trying this code

```
RowHTML = RowHTML.replace(/[0]/g, '[' + (LastIndex + 1) + ']');
```

but it doesn't work, totally ignores the [] and replace every 0 with the [new_number]

any solution ?

Comment: You need to escape the brackets: `/\[0\]/g`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[` and `]` are special characters in regular expressions. They delimit a character class. If you want to match them literally, you need to escape them in the pattern like this:

```
RowHTML = RowHTML.replace(/\[0\]/g, '[' + (LastIndex + 1) + ']');
```

Or as *Fabricio* suggests, you only really need to escape the `[`:

```
RowHTML = RowHTML.replace(/\[0]/g, '[' + (LastIndex + 1) + ']');
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to escape the `]` unless inside of a character class, but the extra escaping won't many any difference anyway.